# iocp.setPresolve(GLPKConstants.GLP_ON); rises an error

Tags: java, glpk

Here is my code :

```
public void solve(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException {
glp_prob lp = null;
glp_tran tran;
glp_iocp iocp;

String fname;
//String res = null;
int skip = 0;
int ret;

// listen to callbacks
GlpkCallback.addListener(this);
// listen to terminal output
GlpkTerminal.addListener(this);

fname = new String(arg[0]);
System.out.println(fname);

lp = GLPK.glp_create_prob();
System.out.println("Problem created");
tran = GLPK.glp_mpl_alloc_wksp();
ret = GLPK.glp_mpl_read_model(tran, fname, skip);
if (ret != 0) {
    GLPK.glp_mpl_free_wksp(tran);
    GLPK.glp_delete_prob(lp);
    System.out.println(ret);
    throw new RuntimeException("Model file not found: " + fname);
}

// generate model
GLPK.glp_mpl_generate(tran, null);
// build model
GLPK.glp_mpl_build_prob(tran, lp);
// set solver parameters
iocp = new glp_iocp();
GLPK.glp_init_iocp(iocp);
iocp.setPresolve(GLPKConstants.GLP_ON);
// do not listen to output anymore
GlpkTerminal.removeListener(this);
    // solve model
ret = GLPK.glp_intopt(lp, iocp);
// postsolve model
if (ret == 0) {
    GLPK.glp_mpl_postsolve(tran, lp, GLPKConstants.GLP_MIP);
    write_lp_solution(lp);
}

// free memory
GLPK.glp_mpl_free_wksp(tran);
GLPK.glp_delete_prob(lp);

// do not listen for callbacks anymore
GlpkCallback.removeListener((GlpkCallbackListener) this);

// check that the hook function has been used for terminal output.
if (!hookUsed) {
    System.out.println("Error: The terminal output hook was not used.");
    System.exit(1);
}
}
```

when i run it i have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gnu.glpk.GLPKJNI.GLP_USE_AT_get()I
at org.gnu.glpk.GLPKJNI.GLP_USE_AT_get(Native Method)
at org.gnu.glpk.GLPKConstants.<clinit>(GLPKConstants.java:74)
at glpk.Optimisation.solve(Optimisation.java:58)
```

The line 58 corresponds to

```
iocp.setPresolve(GLPKConstants.GLP_ON);
```

This code worked well before but since i changed the model to be solved i have this error. 
But when i run it with my terminal

```
glpsol --model -mymodel.mod
```

All works well, the linear problem is solved.
I have to admit that i have no idea from where this error comes.
If anyone can help me...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JNI library is missing in the classpath. Have a look at http://glpk-java.sourceforge.net/architecture.html.